# Odoo 12 Database Restore

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am able to restore the Odoo database on one of our cloud Ubuntu instances. But while referring to that application in Odoo Conf file, we are getting the below error. Same database is working fine in local environment

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
2021-03-02 19:16:03,134 7351 ERROR ? odoo.sql_db: bad query: CREATE SEQUENCE base_registry_signaling INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1

ERROR: relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists

2021-03-02 19:16:03,278 7351 ERROR ? odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry

2021-03-02 19:16:03,281 7351 CRITICAL ? odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `databasename`.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/odoo2/odoo-12/odoo/service/server.py", line 1162, in preload_registries
registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)

File "/home/odoo2/odoo-12/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new
registry.setup_signaling()

File "/home/odoo2/odoo-12/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 378, in setup_signaling
cr.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE base_registry_signaling INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1")

File "/home/odoo2/odoo-12/odoo/sql_db.py", line 148, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo2/odoo-12/odoo/sql_db.py", line 225, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)

psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists

Comment: You'll want to double check and make sure you have an exact, identical copy of the production environment on your local before testing so that you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled on the same problem.
Turns out I dumped the db with the --no-owner option and on import it set the owner to the current user - which was different.

Try setting the owner of the db and tables to the user your're using for odoo.

```
ALTER DATABASE "db_name" OWNER TO user;
-- Assign everything in the currently selected db to 'user'.
REASSIGN OWNED BY other_user TO user;
```